# unable to access Spark web-ui in yarn mode

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I am running a Spark application on a remote cluster setup(of 4 nodes).

When I run the application in **local** mode on the remote machine with the following command,

```
spark-submit --class "Main" --master local[*] target/scala-2.10/myapponspark_2.10-1.0.jar
```

I get the following message in log,

```
INFO ui.SparkUI: Started SparkUI at http://ab2.xxx.in.yyy.com:4041
```

and am able to access the Spark web-UI at http://ab2.xxx.in.yyy.com:4041.

However, when I run in **yarn-client(or yarn-cluster)** mode by giving the following command

```
spark-submit --class "Main" --master yarn-client target/scala-2.10/myapponspark_2.10-1.0.jar
```

the same log message appears stating that Spark web-ui started at the same address as above. But I am unable to access the webpage from browser. What could be the reason?

Comment: Does your job completes without any errors in Yarn mode?

Comment: @Sumit It does complete

Comment: Are you accessing the browser from your machine or from the machine where you have submitted the job?

Answer (score 0):

Try accessing the browser from the machine where you submitted the Spark job. Or ssh using the following command

```
$ssh -X uname@ip_address
```

and then open the firefox from remote using

```
$firefox &
```

may be you can view the Spark UI.